# How to get to Fiori Launchpad with back button in custom App?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am not able to get the back button in my custom Fiori-like app to work. I have added my app to the Fiori Launchpad and tried following code in the press-event:

```
var oCrossAppNavigator = sap.ushell.Container
            .getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");
    oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
        target : {
            semanticObject : "#"
        }
    });
```

This is not working for me. I know there is a Home button but I would like my app to behave like the standard Fiori apps.

Following code works but feels like some sort of dirty hack to me:

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

Installed UI5-Version is 1.28.8

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by using the `shellHash` property instead of `semanticObject`:

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation").toExternal({
    target: {
        shellHash: "#"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that too but with the same result. The console says: "[index.html] the URL is not compliant and may break in a future version # -"

Comment: Yes, it *may*. But for now it is still working for me.

Comment: For me it is doing nothing. Like the code I posted initially.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the SAPUI5 version you are using?